# Moving rows value to another existing column

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a messy datasets as attached below

```
  Sales Credit type      Year     Status
0   NaN          GS      2000  Confirmed
1   NaN           V      2000   Assigned
2    GS        2001  Assigned        NaN
3     V        2004  Received        NaN
```

I am trying to move over the corresponding value into the right columns. So ideally should be like this one.

```
  Sales Credit type  Year     Status
0   NaN          GS  2000  Confirmed
1   NaN           V  2000   Assigned
2   NaN          GS  2001   Assigned
3   NaN           V  2004   Received
```

I have tried to find the solutions in this platforms but no luck. I used `df.loc` to placed the datasets but seems like the result is not like what I expected. I would really appreciate your support for solving this issue. Thank you

*Update

It works with @jezrael solution, thanks! but is it possible if we use it for this case?

```
   ID  Sales Credit_type      Year     Status
0  1   Aston      GS        2000   Confirmed
1  1   NaN        V        2000    Assigned
2  2    GS        2001    Assigned        NaN
3  3    V         2004    Received        NaN
```

And the result should be like this:

```
   ID  Sales Credit_type      Year     Status
0  1   Aston         GS       2000       Confirmed
1  1   NaN           V       2000       Assigned
2  2   NaN          GS       2001       Assigned   
3  3   NaN           V       2004       Received
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. if you are using a `pd.DataFrame`, try `df.head().to_dict(orient='list')` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Hi @ouroboros1, thanks for reminding me. I have edited my question. Would it be sufficient? Sorry it's my second time asking a question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Good attempt. Be sure to write `NaN` next time, not `NAN`, which would simply be the string value `"NAN"`. In fact, the answer by @jezrael will only work if your column `df.Status` contains actual `NaN values` (s/he will simply have corrected this first). Otherwise, it won't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can create mask by last column for test if missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and then use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `axis=1` only for filtered rows:

```
m = df.iloc[:, -1].isna()
df[m] = df[m].shift(axis=1)
print (df)
  Sales Credit type  Year     Status
0   NaN          GS  2000  Confirmed
1   NaN           V  2000   Assigned
2   NaN          GS  2001   Assigned
3   NaN           V  2004   Received
```

If need set all columns without first use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with indexing `.iloc[m, 1:]`:

```
m = df.iloc[:, -1].isna().to_numpy()
df.iloc[m, 1:] = df.iloc[m, 1:].shift(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  Sales Credit_type  Year     Status
0   1  Aston          GS  2000  Confirmed
1   1    NaN           V  2000   Assigned
2   2    NaN          GS  2001   Assigned
3   3    NaN           V  2004   Received
```